# how can i get multiple images from server using url in iOS

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest, nsmutableurlrequest

Hi I am getting single image from server using url in iOS.

my code is like this

```
- (IBAction)overlaysClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"overlays Clicked");
    request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL         URLWithString:@"http://sukhada.co.in/img/overlays/neon/ov1.png"]];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,   NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *localFilePath = [documentsDirectory    stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.jpg"];

    NSData *thedata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL    URLWithString:@"http://sukhada.co.in/img/overlays/neon/ov1.png"]];
    [thedata writeToFile:localFilePath atomically:YES];

    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:thedata];

    self.overlayImgView.image=img;
}
```

To get multiple images from server my code like this

```
NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://sukhada.co.in/img/overlays/neon.zip"];
NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myUrl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
myData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];
NSURLConnection *myConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:myRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
```

//my Array is like this in viewDidload

```
self.overlaysImgsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL    URLWithString:@"http://sukhada.co.in/img/overlays/neon.zip"]];
NSLog(@"urls is %@",overlaysImgsArray);
for (int i=0; i<[overlaysImgsArray count]; i++)  
//download array have url links
{
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[overlaysImgsArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:URL];
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
    {
        if([data length] > 0 && [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",error] isEqualToString:@"(null)"])
        {
            //make your image here from data.
            UIImage *imag = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithData:data]];
            NSArray *array = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *docDir = [array objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *imgstr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
            NSString *pngfilepath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@sample%@.png",docDir,imgstr];
            NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(imag)];
            [data1 writeToFile:pngfilepath atomically:YES];
        }
        else if ([data length] == 0 && [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",error] isEqualToString:@"(null)"])
        {
            NSLog(@"No Data!");
        }
        else if (![[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",error] isEqualToString:@"(null)"]){
            NSLog(@"Error = %@", error);
        }
    }];
    }
}
```

But this is not working for me please anybody suggest me how to get multiple images from server using one url which contains all the images. Please anybody 
thank you in advance

Comment: not getting you issue

Comment: thankyou soo much for replying me ..how to download multiple images from server using url ..i am getting single image from url which contains one image..but not getting multiple images from url which contains multiple images

Comment: you can save png name like 0v1.png.ov2.png....and then pull it all url string is common

Comment: you mean all the png images are saving into one url ? or all png image urls are saved into one common url ?

Comment: actually my issue is downloading images from url i.e display

Comment: actually my issue is downloading images from url i.e displaying in a view when user select any downloadedimage which is applied to mainimage like overlays ..

Comment: please anybody suggest me how to do this i want to download 10 images from server using url

Comment: updated check answer.let me know issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you can try like this 
first you need to save all the 10 image in directory and the fetch one by one as your requirement  .this code save all image from your url

try this

```
- (IBAction)overlaysClicked:(id)sender {


//Note all your image saved with ov1.png,ov2.png......& so . 

       for (int i=1; i<=10; i++) {

    NSString *st2=@"ov";
    NSString *st1=@"http://sukhada.co.in/img/overlays/neon/ov";
    NSString *imageN=[st2 stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
    NSString *imgNameforkey=[imageN stringByAppendingString:@".png"];
    NSString *url=[st1 stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];

    NSString *imgname=[url stringByAppendingString:@".png"];
    NSLog(@" all=%@",imgname);


    NSLog(@"overlays Clicked");
    request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL         URLWithString:imgname]];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,   NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *localFilePath = [documentsDirectory    stringByAppendingPathComponent:imgname];

    NSData *thedata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL    URLWithString:imgname]];
    [thedata writeToFile:localFilePath atomically:YES];


    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:thedata];

    NSLog(@"imgs %@",img);
   // self.overlayImgView.image=img;
       }
}
```

here you can see all image saved [image]

**fetch the image**

using loop or with name

```
NSArray *directoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
NSString *imagePath =  [directoryPath objectAtIndex:0];
imagePath= [imagePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ov1.png"];

 NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
    UIImage *img = = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

download a zip file from url and save it .use this code inside the button action. no need for loop now. try this

```
- (IBAction)overlaysClicked:(id)sender {
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        NSLog(@"Beginning download");
        NSString *stringURL = @"http://sukhada.co.in/img/overlays/neonra.zip";
        NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
        NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

        //Find a cache directory. You could consider using documenets dir instead (depends on the data you are fetching)
        NSLog(@"Got the data!");
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *path = [paths  objectAtIndex:0];

        //Save the data
        NSLog(@"Saving");
        NSString *dataPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"img.zip"];
        dataPath = [dataPath stringByStandardizingPath];
        [urlData writeToFile:dataPath atomically:YES];

    });
}
```

and check you will get img.zip file 
[image]

Comment: please sport tell me where did i wrong.? it shows imgs (nul)

Comment: thankq soo much for suggesting me..i too also have that doubt but when we click on that url its downloading and shows 10 images in downloads folder ..is this process is correct or not?

Comment: otherwise when we click on that url we want to open new tab and display all the 10 images ..is it right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69209/discussion-between-sport-and-vanidasari-ios).

Comment: i am facing another issue ..i have written documentDirectory path in NSLog  ..for every time in loop it shows the same path..when we check that path it shows ov1.png image only but urls are different